# How do i change background color on a Popup element located in a ContentDialog?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I can't figure out how to change the background color of a Popup element opened in a ContentDialog.

```
    <ContentDialog x:Name="MyDialog" MinWidth="600" Height="300" PrimaryButtonText="Close" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True" PrimaryButtonClick="UnicontaOrdersDialog_OnPrimaryButtonClick"  SecondaryButtonText="Ok" SecondaryButtonClick="UnicontaOrdersDialog_OnSecondaryButtonClick" Background="White" Opened="MyDialog_Opened">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border Background="white" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Height="100" Width="100">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">This is a popup. Background should be white</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

[Link to image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eJ38.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the popup is shown within the main XAML window handle by default. You need to make it shown in its own(ContentDialog) top level HWND. To achieve it, you need to use the [ShouldConstrainToRootBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.shouldconstraintorootbounds) property which is introduced from 18362. You need to make your project version is 18362. Then you could set `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False"`.

Because this new property is only available from 18362, I suggest that you use [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml) to detect if it will be available at runtime like the following:

```
xmlns:Windows10version1903="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 8)"

<ContentDialog x:Name="MyDialog" Opened="MyDialog_Opened" Closed="MyDialog_Closed" PrimaryButtonText="Close" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True"   SecondaryButtonText="Ok">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" Width="100" Height="100" Windows10version1903:ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False">
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Width="100" Height="100">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">This is a popup. Background should be white</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```